# Get network bandwidth information

Tags: c#

I use a timer to get bandwidth per second and place that information on a label The output is a large value like `419000KB/S` and next tick it may be `0KB/S`. Is it a problem related to thread or something? I guess it was `bytes` can not update properly, but I have no idea to fix it.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static long bytes = 0;
        static NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        static Label uploadLabel;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            uploadLabel = uploadBandwidth;
            IPv4InterfaceStatistics statistics = adapters[0].GetIPv4Statistics();

            bytes = statistics.BytesSent;
            Timer myTimer = new Timer();
            myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimeUp);
            myTimer.Interval = 1000;
            myTimer.Start();
        }

        public void TimeUp(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            IPv4InterfaceStatistics statistics = adapters[0].GetIPv4Statistics();
            bytes = statistics.BytesSent - bytes;
            Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action<Label>(SetValue), uploadLabel);
        }

        private void SetValue(Label upload)
        {
            upload.Content = ((int)bytes / 1024).ToString() + "KB/s";
        }
    }
```

Update:

The problem is I change the value `bytes` to `statistics.BytesSent - bytes` which is wrong.
Here is the function I modified:

```
public void TimeUp(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    IPv4InterfaceStatistics statistics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()[0].GetIPv4Statistics();
    long bytesPerSec = statistics.BytesReceived - bytes;
    bytes = statistics.BytesReceived;
    String speed = (bytesPerSec / 1024).ToString() + "KB/S";
    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action<Label, String>(SetValue), uploadLabel, speed);
}

private void SetValue(Label upload, String speed)
{
    upload.Content = speed;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with your logic.

At the beginning, you store the data sent so far in `bytes`:

```
uploadLabel = uploadBandwidth;
IPv4InterfaceStatistics statistics = adapters[0].GetIPv4Statistics();

bytes = statistics.BytesSent; // initialize bytes to amount already sent
```

And then on each event, you reset the value to contain `BytesSent` - `bytes`:

```
IPv4InterfaceStatistics statistics = adapters[0].GetIPv4Statistics();
bytes = statistics.BytesSent - bytes;
```

So assuming that you start with 15k sent and send 1kB every second, the variables will be as follows:

```
|| seconds elapsed | BytesSent | bytes ||
||=================|===========|=======||
||        0        |   15000   | 15000 ||
||        1        |   16000   |  1000 ||
||        2        |   17000   | 16000 ||
||        3        |   18000   |  2000 ||
```

So as you can see, the `bytes` value is alternating and not showing any legitimate value in any of the cases except for the first one.

In order to fix your problem, you'll either need to introduce a second state variable or pass the bytes value to the `SetValue` method in a correct manner similar to answer by @Sign:

```
public void TimeUp(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    IPv4InterfaceStatistics statistics = adapters[0].GetIPv4Statistics();
    var sent = statistics.BytesSent - bytes;
    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action<Label>(SetValue), uploadLabel, sent);
    bytes = statistics.BytesSent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! When you writing this comment I've found that :), still appreciated for your comment